# Prime Order $\Rightarrow$ Cyclic $\Rightarrow$ Abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Is this correct?

If a group has prime order $p$, then it is cyclic since it all nonidentity elements have order $p$ by Cauchy's theorem.

If it is cyclic, then it is abelian since every element is a power of the generator.

Thus, every group of prime order is abelian.

Comment: Yep! Although it seems you mean "group" rather than "subgroup" in the first sentence.

Comment: The duplicate has many different proofs, i.e., using either Lagrange, or Cauchy based on Lagrange, or even Cauchy without Lagrange.